# Convert char to short

Tags: c, char, short

I need to copy the data from 2 `char` (8 bit long) to a single `short` (16 bit long). I tried two different ways, but can't get it to work.

```
void char2short(char* pchar, short* pshort)
{
    memcpy(pshort    , pchar + 1    , 1);
    memcpy(pshort + 1, pchar    , 1);
}
```

And the other one:

```
void char2short(char* pchar, short* pshort)
{
   short aux;
   aux = ((*pchar & 0x00FF) << 8) | ((*(pchar+1) & 0xFF00) >> 8);
   *pshort = aux;
}
```

Comment: You can't use memcpy this way, because ist cannot cast these dataytpes automaticallay. You need to iterate over the src array and cast every value to short

Comment: You need to know if the short is represented as [little-endian or big-endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Comment: You need to know the endianness of pchar and pshort. If they are the same, use `memcpy((void *)pshort, (const void*)pchar, sizeof(short));`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>


void char2short(unsigned char* pchar, unsigned short* pshort)
{
  *pshort = (pchar[0] << 8) | pchar[1];
}

int main()
{
  unsigned char test[2];
  unsigned short result = 0;

  test[0] = 0xAB;
  test[1] = 0xCD;
  char2short(test, &result);
  printf("%#X\n",result);
  return 0;
}
```

this will do the job.

Comment: Endianess is not an issue here, at least when assuming the data under `pchar` does not change depending on the system's endianess, which is not the case in your example.

Comment: If this is a 16 bit system you'll get problems when left shifting a signed number 8 bits. That invokes undefined behavior. Don't use the sloppy default integer types when writing bit hacks!

Comment: Checking out here a few years later to tell you your answer help me get my thesis done and therefore my degree title! You rock!

Comment: Gratulation. Good to hear that I could help you.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming `pchar` is an array that contains your 2 chars, how about:

```
*pshort = (uint16_t)(((unsigned int)pchar[0]) |
                    (((unsigned int)pchar[1])<<8));
```

P.S. This work for little endianess.

Comment: Endianess is not an issue here, at least when assuming the data under `pchar` does not change depending on the system's endianess.

Answer (score 5):

Others didn't explain why *your* code didn't work, so I'll take a quick stab at it:

```
memcpy(pshort    , pchar + 1    , 1);
memcpy(pshort + 1, pchar    , 1);
```

Adding to a pointer `TYPE * p` moves the pointer by increments of `sizeof( TYPE )` (so it does point at the next element, remember this is only *defined* if *inside* an array). So while `pchar + 1` is correct, `pshort + 1` is not (as it's addressing the next `short`).

```
aux = ((*pchar & 0x00FF) << 8) | ((*(pchar+1) & 0xFF00) >> 8);
```

Errr.... the right hand side is broken in more ways than one. First, `*(pchar+1)` is a `char`, and `& 0xFF00` on a `char` will always yield 0 (because a `char` is only 8 bits to begin with, at least on contemporary machines...). And then you shift that 8 bits to the right...?

And just in case you weren't aware of it, if you hadn't used 0x00FF on the left hand side (promoting `*pchar` to the width of the right-hand operand) but (`char`-sized) 0xFF, the result of that operation would still be of type `char`, and shifting that 8 bits to the left doesn't make much sense either (as the type doesn't get expanded magically).

---

Another way to go about this not mentioned yet is the `union`:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 struct chars_t
 {
     // could also go for char[2] here,
     // whichever makes more sense semantically...
     char first;
     char second;
 };

 union combo_t
 {
      // elements of a union share the memory, i.e.
      // reside at the same address, not consecutive ones
      short shrt;
      struct chars_t chrs;
 };

 int main()
 {
     union combo_t x;
     x.chrs.first = 0x01;
     x.chrs.second = 0x02;
     printf( "%x", x.shrt );
     return 0;
  }
```

If you're using this in a larger context, beware of struct padding.

Comment: The union will make the code endianess-dependent. On a big endian system you will get the expected result 0x0102 but on little endian systems you will get 0x0201. And then indeed there's the padding hazard. So union is not a good idea, use bit shifts instead.

Comment: @Lundin: Depending on your needs, the endianess-dependent result might actually be what you're looking for. ;-) But I agree, `union` is somewhat dodgy. I included it for completeness' sake.

Comment: Why would you intentionally want write endianess-dependent code? Endianess is a 100% bad thing no matter system.

Comment: @Lundin: I've come across systems once or twice where the existing APIs *required* me to write code that behaved differently depending on endianess. (Usually because the other party didn't bother to cater for endianess in the first place.) Sometimes changing existing APIs is not an option.

Answer (score 3):

When doing bitwise operations, use robust code with real fixed-size integers, of known signedness. This will prevent you from writing bugs related to implicit type conversions, causing unintended signedness. The `char` type is particularly dangerous, since it has implementation-defined signedness. It should never be used for storing numbers.

```
#include <stdint.h>

void char2short(const uint8_t* pchar, uint16_t* pshort)
{
  *pshort = ((uint16_t)pchar[0] << 8) | (uint16_t)pchar[1];
}
```